# RequireJS error callback (errback) not getting called

Tags: javascript, error-handling, requirejs

I'm writing a modular web app using RequireJS for module loading and dependency injection.

From my `bootstrap.js` file I load `Application.js` and initialize it, passing in an array of modules that are to be "loaded"*(1)* by the `Application`. When the initialization finishes, the `Application` will call a function to signal that it's done loading.

I'm loading the modules asynchronously (in regard to each other) using `require(["module"], callback(module), callback(error))`.

The problem that I'm having with this is that the error callback (errback) is not called when a module fails to load (at least on Chrome when the server responds with a 404 status code).

I can see the error in the Google Chrome Developer Tools Console, but the errback isn't called:

```
GET http://192.168.1.111:8812/scripts/modules/InexistentModule/manifest.js 404 (Not Found) 
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: modules/InexistentModule/manifest
```

Has anyone experienced gotten around this issue with RequireJS errbacks? If so, how?

*(1) Actually, I'm just loading module manifests, not the entire modules, so that I can display icons for them and register their routes using Backbone.SubRoute*

The libraries that I'm using (none of them are minified):

- RequireJS 1.0.8
- Underscore 1.6.0
- jQuery 1.11.0
- Backbone 1.1.2
- Backbone.SubRoute 0.4.1

Out of the libraries above, only RequireJS and Underscore are used directly by me at the moment.

I've used Underscore for currying when passing the success/failure callbacks to Require in order to pass in the `i` from my loop as the `index` parameter. For the success callback, this works wonderfully and I think that this does not affect the errback (I've tested with a simple function of arity 1, instead of the partial function returned by `_.partial` and the function is still not called in case of a 404 error).

I'll post my `bootstrap.js` and `Application.js` files here as they might provide more info on this.

Thank you!

**bootstrap.js**

```
require.config({
    catchError: true,
    enforceDefine: true,
    baseUrl: "./scripts",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "lib/jquery",
        "underscore": "lib/underscore",
        "backbone": "lib/backbone",
        "backbone.subroute": "lib/backbone.subroute"
    },
    shim: {
        "underscore": {
            deps: [],
            exports: "_"
        },
        "backbone": {
            deps: ["jquery", "underscore"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        "backbone.subroute": {
            deps: ["backbone"],
            exports: "Backbone.SubRoute"
        }
    }
});

define(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone", "Application"],
    function ($, _, Backbone, Application) {
        var modules = ["Home", "ToS", "InexistentModule"];
        var defaultModule = "Home";

        var onApplicationInitialized = function()
        {
            require(["ApplicationRouter"], function(ApplicationRouter){
                ApplicationRouter.initialize();
            });
        }

        Application.initialize(modules, defaultModule, onApplicationInitialized); 
    }
);
```

**Application.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'],
function($,_,Backbone){
    var modules;
    var manifests = [];
    var routers = [];
    var defaultModule = "";

    var totalModules = 0;
    var loadedModules = 0;
    var failedModules = 0;
    var onCompleteCallback = function(){};

    var onModuleManifestLoadComplete = function(index, manifest){
        manifests[index] = manifest;
        console.log("Load manifest for module: " + modules[index] + " complete");
        //TODO: init module 
        loadedModules++;
        if(totalModules == (loadedModules + failedModules))
            onCompleteCallback();
    };

    var onModuleManifestLoadFailed = function(index, err){
        console.log("Load manifest for module: " + modules[index] + " failed");
        failedModules++;
        if(totalModules == (loadedModules + failedModules))
            onCompleteCallback();
    }; 

    var initialize = function(_modules, _defaultModule, callback){
        defaultModule = _defaultModule;
        modules = _modules;
        manifests = Array(modules.length);
        totalModules = modules.length;
        onCompleteCallback = callback;

        for(i=0; i<modules.length; i++){
            require(['modules/'+modules[i]+'/manifest'], 
                _.partial(onModuleManifestLoadComplete, i),
                _.partial(onModuleManifestLoadFailed, i));
        };
    };

    return {
        modules: modules,
        manifests: manifests,
        routers: routers,
        defaultModule: defaultModule,
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

Comment: Yes, the `onModuleManifestLoadComplete` works and it gets called for every one of the existing `manifest.js` files after they've loaded.

Comment: If all the modules exits the `onCompleteCallback` gets called too and the `Router` in `bootstrap.js` gets initialized. The problem appears when at least one module fails to load.

Comment: If you test with *only one* non-existing module to be loaded by the code you show in your question, does the errback get called as you'd expect? Also (this is a long shot but some questions on SO were resolved this way, so...) are you running the very latest version of RequireJS?

Comment: I've just tested with only one inexistent module and the errback does not get called. I've added the library versions to my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You indicate you are using RequireJS 1.0.8. I've checked the documentation for the 1.x series and find nothing about errbacks. This [page](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Upgrading-to-RequireJS-2.0) actually indicates that errbacks were introduced in the 2.x series.

Also the `shim` is something that was introduced in the 2.x series. So right now, RequireJS is ignoring your shims.

Comment: Wow! Thank you :) I think that I might have landed on the 1.x page when searching for the "latest" version and updating the lib. I've updated the library to 2.1.11 and the errback is getting called. I wouldn't have though of checking the version further. Thank you, again!